# TYPO3 - inline FLUID - add a Space

Tags: php, typo3, inline, fluid

I am searching for a Example or Solution.
I have a inline for each and I need a Space after the Items

```
{items -> f:for(each: '{field.referenzTeaserCategory -> dce:explode(delimiter:\',\')}', as: 'items', iteration: 'iterator')}
```

The Output is "cat1cat2cat3" but i need the Output with a Space, like this: "cat1 cat2 cat3"

Thanks for a Solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use an Partial File to solve it:

MyPartial.html

```
<f:spaceless>
  <f:for each="{field.referenzTeaserCategory -> dce:explode(delimiter:',')}" as="item" iteration="iterator">
    {item}
  </f:for>
</f:spaceless>
```

You can also use Sections within your template:

MyTemplate.html

```
<div class="{f:render(section:'myCategories', arguments:_all)}"></div>

<f:section name="MyCategories"><f:spaceless>
  <f:for each="{field.referenzTeaserCategory -> dce:explode(delimiter:',')}" as="item" iteration="iterator">
    {item}
  </f:for>
</f:spaceless></f:section>
```

Comment: thanks, jep i think that is the right way, but the output is empty :(

Comment: Then you should check if {field.referenzTeaserCategory} exist, and has an value. maybe use `<f:debug>{field.referenzTeaserCategory}</f:debug>` or `<f:debug>{field.referenzTeaserCategory -> dce:explode(delimiter:',')}</f:debug>` if the explode is working

Comment: this works very fine: <f:for each="{field.referenzTeaserCategory -> dce:explode(delimiter:',')}" as="item" iteration="iterator">{item}</f:for>

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can build this with inline notation with normal fluid.
You need to use a viewhelper which concatenates your variable `items` with a string `' '`. You may introduce this VH or use tag notation:

```
<f:for each="{field.referenzTeaserCategory -> dce:explode(delimiter:',')}" as="items" iteration="iterator">{items} </f:for>
```

BTW: really item**s**? it is only one item (at a time)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used an inline foreach yet but maybe an whitespapce after the closing curly bracket will work.

like this:
`'{field.referenzTeaserCategory -> dce:explode(delimiter:\',\')} '`

Comment: when i use the spacer after the } its a error: The argument "each" was registered with type "array", but is of type "string" in view helper